# CSS Media Queries : device-width on desktop

Tags: ipad, html, css, media-queries

i have a sepcific question related to using CSS Media Queries.
Like when we say device-width for the iPad, I think it always returns 768px (both orientations)
But on desktop browsers, what exactly is the value returned for device-width ?
Is it different from what "width" would return in the Media Query for desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec allows you to access both:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

> device-width: Describes the width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window).
>
> width: The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the width of the page box on a printer).

So device-width is the width of the display hardware, be it the phone itself or the desktop monitor. Obviously, not that useful in a desktop situation given that the screen size has little bearing on the browser viewport size.

Comment: Thx a lot...so if i use media queries to differentiate between desktop/iPhone/iPad using device-width, how do i specify it for the desktop....i know iPhone can be through max 480px...ipad can be through equal 768px....But how do i specify the device-width for desktop...i mean i wanted the 3 separate CSS link statements..

Comment: Also to confirm, are width and device width indirectly the same values on iPhone/iPad?